# Wordpress - get total No. of meta_key for author

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Running a voting system on my site that lets users vote on posts with the standard up/down type thing.

I'm trying to run a query on author pages to get the total number of 'votes' that author has attributed to them over all the posts they've made.

Small problem is that when the author has zero votes it displays the total number of votes from the meta_key value for every author on the site.

Code:-

```
 <?php 

function author_rating_total() {
   $user_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
   $query = array (
       'author' => $user_id,
       'suppress_filters' => 'true', //lets skip some unnessecery sql queries
       'posts_per_page' => -1
   );
   $queryObject = new WP_Query($query); while($queryObject->have_posts()) : $queryObject->the_post();

   $post_ratings_data = get_post_custom(get_the_id());
   $post_ratings_score = intval($post_ratings_data['votecount'][0]);

   $ratings_array[] = $post_ratings_score;

   endwhile; 

   $ratings_sum = array_sum($ratings_array);

   if ($ratings_sum > 0) {
         $ratings_sum = '' . $ratings_sum;
   }  

   echo $ratings_sum;   

   wp_reset_query();
}
?>

<?php 

echo author_rating_total();


?>
```

How do I return the value 0 instead of the total number of that meta_key?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code other than you aren't initializing `$ratings_array` before you enter the loop. If you're using that variable elsewhere, it may be the root cause.

Comment: Yeah, it works just fine, except if the author as no ratings on any of their posts it returns the total number of ratings all authors have received, combined. :/